# How to compare values of different table rows in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have two different tables like this...

```
TblDepartment : DeptId, DeptName

TblEmployee : EmpId, DeptId, DeptName
```

Now due to some error there are some wrong mappings in employee table of deptId and deptName (DeptName mapped with wrong DeptId)

I want to figure out those DeptIds...

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Join the two tables based on dept id and select the results where department name are not equal using where clause. Also the question should state what have you tried and which table contains the correct data.

Comment: What's the point, however, of storing the department name and department id in the employee table? Part of having a foreign key is that the only information you store is said key; the rest of the related information is in the foriegn table. `DeptName` should *not* be a column in the table `tblEmployee`. When you need the name, `JOIN` to `TblDepartment`.

Comment: I know there is no point of storing data in such manner, but it is 10 year old application and I can't change it now

Comment: *"I can't change it now"* Yes you can. Something that has been wrong for years doesn't make it "right".

Comment: It has 40 lakh+ rows, making changes in it will be very time consuming

Comment: You have sufficient experience to write that trivial query - time to step up and make an effort. I suggest a join rather than using EXISTS to actually see the difference in names. If you don't have a foreign key on the ID column (which seems likely) you might want to outer join to find employees with department information that is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to get all the employees for which their `DeptId` and `DeptName` do not match (both) a department:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM TblEmployee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM TblDepartment d 
  WHERE d.DeptId = e.DeptId AND d.DeptName = e.DeptName
)
```

Answer (score 1):

one of the best solutions for comparing two tables is using checksum like the below link :

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/on-comparing-tables-in-sql-server/